# OpenMP more threads drastically increases total time

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I am writing a Pi estimator for class.  The point is to estimate Pi using OpenMP and to analyze the speedup provided by using three separate schedules, static, dynamic and guided.  However my total time skyrockets when I add threads.  My total time for 1 thread is around 21 seconds, and for 2 threads is roughly 145 seconds.  I can't figure out why.  Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <omp.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


void computePi(int, int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
cout.precision(20);
omp_set_dynamic(0);
int i, p;
int  n;

// loop {number of iterations} [number of threads]
if (argc > 1)
{
    n = atoll(argv[1]);
    p = atoi(argv[2]);
}
else
{
    n = 10000000;
    p = 8;
}
printf("Debug: dart throws = %d \n", n);
printf("Debug: number of requested threads = %d\n", p);

omp_set_num_threads(p);

double time = omp_get_wtime();

//dispArray(a,n);
computePi(n, p);

time = omp_get_wtime() - time;
printf("Total time = %f seconds \n ", time);

return 0;
}


void computePi(int n, int p) {

omp_set_num_threads(p);


int i;
int hits = 0;
srand(time(NULL));
double timeStatic = omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp parallel for shared(i) schedule(static) reduction(+:hits)
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        float r, x, xdiff, y, ydiff;

        x = (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
        y = (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;

        if (y > .50)
        {
            ydiff = y - .50;
        }
        else
        {
            ydiff = .50 - y;
        }
        if (x > .50)
        {
            xdiff = x - .50;
        }
        else
        {
            xdiff = .50 - x;
        }
        xdiff *= xdiff;
        ydiff *= ydiff;
        r = sqrt(ydiff + xdiff);


        if (r <= .50)
        {
            hits += 1;
        }
    }
    timeStatic = omp_get_wtime() - timeStatic;
    float percentage;
    percentage = (float)hits / (float)n;

    cout << "Static Loop" << endl;
    cout << "Hit Percentage: " << percentage * 100 << "%" << endl;
    cout << "Pi Estimation: " << percentage * 4 << endl;
    cout << "Time Taken: " << timeStatic << endl << endl;

    hits = 0;
    double timeDynamic = omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp parallel for shared(i) schedule(dynamic) reduction(+:hits)
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        float r, x, xdiff, y, ydiff;

        x = (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
        y = (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;

        if (y > .50)
        {
            ydiff = y - .50;
        }
        else
        {
            ydiff = .50 - y;
        }
        if (x > .50)
        {
            xdiff = x - .50;
        }
        else
        {
            xdiff = .50 - x;
        }
        xdiff *= xdiff;
        ydiff *= ydiff;
        r = sqrt(ydiff + xdiff);


        if (r <= .50)
        {
            hits += 1;
        }
    }
    timeDynamic = omp_get_wtime() - timeDynamic;
    percentage = (float)hits / (float)n;


    cout << "Dynamic Loop" << endl;
    cout << "Hit Percentage: " << percentage * 100 << "%" << endl;
    cout << "Pi Estimation: " << percentage * 4 << endl;
    cout << "Time Taken: " << timeDynamic << endl << endl;

    hits = 0;
    double timeGuided = omp_get_wtime();
#pragma omp parallel for shared(i) schedule(guided) reduction(+:hits)
    for (i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        float r, x, xdiff, y, ydiff;

        x = (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;
        y = (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;

        if (y > .50)
        {
            ydiff = y - .50;
        }
        else
        {
            ydiff = .50 - y;
        }
        if (x > .50)
        {
            xdiff = x - .50;
        }
        else
        {
            xdiff = .50 - x;
        }
        xdiff *= xdiff;
        ydiff *= ydiff;
        r = sqrt(ydiff + xdiff);


        if (r <= .50)
        {
            hits += 1;
        }
    }
    timeGuided = omp_get_wtime() - timeGuided;
    percentage = (float)hits / (float)n;

    cout << "Guided Loop" << endl;
    cout << "Hit Percentage: " << percentage * 100 << "%" << endl;
    cout << "Pi Estimation: " << percentage * 4 << endl;
    cout << "Time Taken: " << timeGuided << endl << endl;



    return;

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Two obvious problems: 1/ `shared(i)`: just think about it and you'll see this is nonsense; 2/ as explained several times in SO already ([see here for example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40278404/5239503)) `rand()` isn't thread-safe. Try fixing these 2 and we'll see if you still have your performance issues.

Comment: Besides what Gilles has already pointed out, a small tip: use `xdiff = 0.5 * (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX;` to achieve the same as convoluted `if`/`else` logic with double the precision. Same applies to `ydiff`. Also, the default chunk size for `dynamic` schedule is 1, which means **HUGE** overhead in your case.