# Thread-safe parallel RNG slower than sequential rand()

Tags: c++, random, parallel-processing, thread-safety, openmp

I use this version of calculation of Pi with thread-safe function

```
rand_r
```

But it appears that it is slower (and answer is wrong) when running this program in parallel comparing to sequential program with use of

```
rand()
```

which is not thread-safe. It seems that this way of using is also not thread-safe. But I do not understand why, because I have read many questions about thread-safe PRNGs and learned that rand_r should be safe enough.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
#include "omp.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

unsigned seed;

int main()
{
double start = time(0);

int i, n, N;
double x, y;



N = 1<<30;
n = 0;

double pi;



#pragma omp threadprivate(seed)
#pragma omp parallel private(x, y) reduction(+:n) 
{

for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
seed = 25234 + 17 * omp_get_thread_num();
    x = rand_r(&seed) / (double) RAND_MAX;
    y = rand_r(&seed) / (double) RAND_MAX;

    if (x*x + y*y <= 1)
        n++;
}
}

pi = 4. * n / (double) (N);

cout << pi << endl;

double stop = time(0);

cout << (stop - start) << endl;

return 0;
}
```

P.S. By the way, what are the magic numbers in

```
seed = 25234 + 17 * omp_get_thread_num();
```

? I stole them from some answer.

**EDIT:** The comment by Gilles helped me. The resolution was:
1. To switch lines of for loop and seed initialization.
2. To add #pragma omp for

Modified code reads

```
#pragma omp parallel private(x, y, seed)
{
seed = 25234 + 17 * omp_get_thread_num();

#pragma omp for reduction(+:n)
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

    x = (double) rand_r(&seed) / (double) RAND_MAX;
    y = (double) rand_r(&seed) / (double) RAND_MAX;

    if (x*x + y*y <= 1)
       n++;
}

}
```

The problem is resolved.

Comment: What do you mean by answer is wrong?  Are you expecting rand_r to support a separate sequence for each thread?  Surely, not more than one of those sequences would match a single thread invocation of the same generator.  I suppose a true PRNG would be considered "wrong" if any 2 threads fell into the same sequence, but when you take shortcuts using a non-parallel generator you don't have such assurance.

Comment: @tim18 By "answer is wrong" I mean that the resulting value of Pi is not 3.14 (but it is 3.14 when using sequential program with rand() ). Yes, I am expecting separate sequences for each thread, because I am using seed dependent on the number of the thread. Or am I missing something?..

Comment: Yes you miss something: you mustn't initialise your seed at each iteration of the loop, but once and only once. The way you do it ATM, you will generate again and again the very same "random" number.

Comment: @Gilles OK, I see, thank you. But how do I get different seed for each thread then?..

Comment: The same way you do it now (for example) but just swapping the `for` line and the initialization line...

Comment: Another problem is that you don't distribute your loop. Overall, I could reuse the exact same answer as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40278404/5239503)

Comment: @Gilles Oh, thank you very much. I guess I was completely confused, of course I should swap the for line and the initialization one. Thank you for the link, I will read it.

Comment: @Gilles Oh, I just thought, that if there is #pragma omp parallel and for-loop is inside this construction, it is equivalent to #pragma omp parallel for

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there are more instructions in rand_r() compared to rand(). Below is copied from one implementation. So it's reasonable that rand_r() takes more time to complete one round than rand().

```
int
rand_r(unsigned int *ctx)
{
    u_long val = (u_long) *ctx;
    int r = do_rand(&val);

    *ctx = (unsigned int) val;
    return (r);
}


static u_long next = 1;

int
rand()
{
    return (do_rand(&next));
}
```

And since rand() is not thread safe, the output could be incorrect if you use rand() in parallel. The worse part is that you would still get a result and don't know if it's correct in small scale test.

Comment: Okay. Maybe I can can some benefit for random number generation in parallel way using some libraries for parallel random number generation?.. By the way, I've looked through the same questions as mine and recommendation was to use rand_r to improve performance. And the time of  pi evaluation indeed decreased comparing to sequential program. That's why it is strange for me that in my case time is increased instead.
And still I do not understand why the result with rand_r() in parallel is incorrect (pi is not equal to 3.14), but it's correct while using rand() sequentially.